# best practices for multiple listener on single event in ionic

Tags: events, ionic-framework, ionic2, xmpp

I am working on ionic framework, i have used events which is used to publish and subscribe. example is below...

```
this.events.publish('user:created', user);//publishing on first page

//subscribing on second page
events.subscribe('user:created', (user) => {
  console.log('Welcome', user);
 });
```

i want to know if i use multiple subscribe event on other page like...

```
//subscribing on third page
events.subscribe('user:created', (user) => {
  console.log('Welcome', user);
 });
```

1) what will be impact on application, does it will increase the load on 
application or anything else problem occurred?

and so does events are published while making chat with XMPP server, server published events like...

```
this.client.on('message:sent', function (msg) {
      console.log("message:sent");
      console.log(msg);
);

 this.client.on('pubsub:event', function (msg) {
      console.log("pubsub:event");
      console.log(msg);
);

 this.client.on('message', function (msg) {
      console.log("message");
      console.log(msg);
      );

this.client.on('stanza', function (msg) {
      console.log("stanza")

      console.log(msg);
    });
```

2) what will be impact on app if i use same event listeners multiple times?  does it will increase the load on application or anything else problem occurred? or any other side effect? power consumption or resource utilise related issue?